# STL list iterator outside of range

Tags: c++, list, stl, containers

I can't know why this error happened in my code.(Actually, this is my first time to use std:: list.) When I use it++ it makes error 'list iterator outside of range', and when I use ++it it makes error 'list iterator not incrementable'. Please help me!

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
typedef struct tag_vpos { int data; list <int>::iterator pos; } vpos;
list<int> row[100];
stack<vpos> save[100];
int col[100][100], n, r, rowsize[100];
//int row[100][100];
long long cnt;
void arr(int x, int y) {
 list<int>::iterator it = row[y].begin();
 while (it != row[y].end()) {
  if (!col[x][*it]) {
   vpos t = { *it, it }, temp;
   int val = *it;

   col[x][val] = 1;
   row[y].erase(it++);
   save[y].push(t);
   if (x == r - 1) { // if x th column is the end of right
    if (y == r - 1) cnt++; // if y th column is the bottom, count this 
    else arr(0, y + 1);// else fill next row, first column 
   }
   else { arr(x + 1, y); } // else fill next right square
   temp = save[y].top();
   row[y].insert(temp.pos, temp.data);
   save[y].pop();
   col[x][temp.data] = 0;
  }
  else it++;
 }
 return;
}
void main() {
 printf("Input n, r (paint r x r field with n colors, same color cannot be used in same column and row) \n: ");
 scanf("%d %d", &n, &r);
 for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) row[i].push_back(j);
  rowsize[i] = n;
 }
 printf("start\n");
 arr(0, 0);
 printf("There are %ld ways to paint.\n", cnt);
}
```

Comment: This `row[y].erase(it++);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The returned iterator from [`std::list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) is provided for the very reason you seem to need. Perhaps `it = row[y].erase(it);` ?

Comment: As their name implies, iterators are for iterating. Using them as pointers usually only causes grief.

Comment: The erase() function removes the intended element from the Container and returns you an iterator pointing to the next valid element if any. So while removing elements from the iterator no need to increment the iterator after erase, since the return value of erase will be the iterator pointing to valid element if any. If no element present it will return Container.end().

Comment: row[y].remove_if(*it); Tried   row[y].insert(temp.pos, temp.data);

Answer (score 0):

To remove elements from STL container while iterating you combine the container's [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) function (they all have this) with the [remove or remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm. Otherwise your invalidating your iterators underneath yourself.

```
void delete_elements(std::list &list) 
{ 
    list.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            list.begin(),
            list.end(), 
            [](char x){return std::isspace(x);}),
        list.end() );
}
```

Comment: There is a [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) member function that is much simpler for this case.